# Is it possible to determine if a resource is hosted on BlobStore by only looking at the URL?

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore

Lets say I have an app that has images hosted in various places... some of them being BlobStore.  I want to write a showThumbnail() helper that will take a URL and generate an  tag with height/width.  Some of these images are hosted on servers that can do dynmic resizing... like in BlobStore I can specify s=xxx to resize it... where other services use different parameters.

is it possible for me to look at the URL and determine that the image is being hosted by BlobStore, so that I know which query params to append for dynamic resizing?  the URLs I see look like *.ggpht.com ... will this always be the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For blobstore in general, @waffle paradox is correct - a blob can be served by any handler, transparently. I presume you're asking not just about Blobstore though, but specifically about the fast image serving support. In that case, yes, they'll all be served off the `ggpht.com` domain - but that's an implementation detail, and could theoretically change in future, so you'd be far better off embedding some metadata in your page that indicates that it's a blobstore image.

Comment: ur right, thats what I meant (image serving service).  I should have thought the question thru a bit more

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by `*.ggpht.com` and where you saw it, but the short answer is: no.  The [blobstore documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html) states that to serve blobs, you have to define your own serving/downloading handler, so there's no way to tell if something is hosted on the blobstore simply by the URL.

For your problem, I would suggest tracking which images come from the blobstore if you can, or re-organizing the way the hosting is done (if you can).

Comment: thanks waffle.  u answered the actual question, but now I've realized I didn't ask the question clearly enough, and Nick actually answered my intended question